# Is it possible to ignore "Inbox" folder when using IMAP (mbsync)?

Tags: email, imap

I can't find a clear answer whether "Inbox" folder is necessary to sync when using IMAP protocol. I can't seem to uncheck it on gmail and mbsyncrc (mbsync's config file) seems to require an "Inbox" entry otherwise it creates one in default location.

This is quite unfortunate, because when syncing gmail Inbox contains both primary as well as "spam" categories (promotions and social), which you ideally would like to filter out (by using labels and syncing those instead).

Could anyone please confirm if "Inbox" is strictly necessary when using IMAP or if there are any workarounds to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have worked was adding `!"INBOX"` keyword to the `Patterns` entry in the `.mbsyncrc` file:

`Patterns * !"INBOX" ![Gmail]* "[Gmail]/Sent Mail" "[Gmail]/Starred"`

Early test seems to have confirmed that (email sent to yourself wasn't updated in Inbox folder but landed correctly in the "primary" label), but only time will tell. If anyone sees any flaw in this already please let me know.